# Why is Bash used in the Command Line for OSX

Tags: c, macos, bash, command-line

According to Wikipedia, Mac OSX was written primarily in C (which makes sense because it is a UNIX like OS). Additional languages used were C++ and Objective-C. If this is the case, why do I have to use BASH to communicate with the OS on the Command Line? Why is BASH used in the command line in an OS that was written in C? Are there any reasons why C is not used, as this is the primary language used to create the OS.

Comment: csh is the standard bsd shell, but bash was waaayyyy more popular when osx came out.

Comment: You seem to have your layers of operating system all confused.

Comment: Despite being a basic to the point of naive question, it's actually clear and answerable. I neither DVed or voted to close it.

Comment: Because `C` makes a rotten interactive language?

Comment: Perhaps its worth noting that [bash itself is written in c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/).  As I would assume are most or all common shells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The same could be said of Unix, Linux, etc. There's nothing special about OS X in your question.
2. Bash is interpreted. C is compiled. An interpreted language is required for something that can be typed live and run.
3. You really want to fat finger a regular expression and blow out your
   hard drive because you messed up your array bounds checking? (Which is surprisingly easy to do in bash nonetheless.)

As for why bash and not csh, or heck, Python or Ruby, that's getting more historical and / or opinion based. Even if I were knowledgeable on this, that would be out of scope here.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. Wasn't really prepared for the outlast against my question! Additional praise for not just simply down voting, but taking time to answer.